# DeleteRequest example with elastic java api client 8.2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need example for DeleteRequest with respect to ES 8.2.0 Java Api client where we don't have type. we have only index and documents.  I am looking for code reference where I want to delete one particular document by passing index name and doc id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code for deleting document from index. You need to provide `index_name` and `doc_id` to delete document.

```java
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();
ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
ElasticsearchClient esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

DeleteRequest request = DeleteRequest.of(d -> d.index("index_name").id("doc_id"));
DeleteResponse response = esClient.delete(request);
```

Comment: could you please point me to some code reference urls for new java api client as I don't able to find much around the same.

Comment: @Mrbond You can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html) documentation but still it is In Progress and dont cover all the topic. You can see [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/281) GitHub issue as well for uncomplete documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out

**Syntax:**

```
DeleteRequest request = new DeleteRequest("your-index-name","doc-id");
```

**Example:**

```
DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest("employeeindex","002");
DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
         System.out.println("response id: "+deleteResponse.getId());
```

for more information

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-delete.html

Comment: This is deprecated. There is new Java-client release by ES.